# How to detect a touch inside a box2d fixture created by PhyicsEditor in Cocos2d-x?

Tags: touch, box2d, physics, cocos2d-x

My testing environment:

Xcode 4.6, New cocos2d-x+box2d project
cocos2d-2.1beta3-x-2.1.1
PhysicsEditor 1.0.10

I modified a bit in [HelloWorldScene of PhysicsEditor cocos2dx demo](http://www.codeandweb.com/blog/2012/05/07/physicseditor-cocos2d-x-box2d) to make it simpler, Here are some of my code:

1. initPhysics

   gravity.Set(0.0f, 0.0f);

So that the sprite will not move.

2. Replace source code inside ccTouchesEnded to:

   CCTouch* pTouch = (CCTouch *)touches->anyObject();

   CCPoint location = pTouch->locationInView(pTouch->view());

   CCPoint convLoc = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(location);

   b2Vec2 v = b2Vec2(convLoc.x/PTM_RATIO, convLoc.y/PTM_RATIO);

   for (b2Body *b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext())
   {

   ```
   b2Fixture *f = b->GetFixtureList(); // get the first fixture
   CCSprite *sprite =(CCSprite *) b->GetUserData();

   if(sprite != NULL)
   {
       if(f -> TestPoint(v))
       {
           CCLog("You touched a body %d",sprite->getTag());
       }
   }
   ```

   }

The problem is that TestPoint only return true in a very small area (not for whole shape area).

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Can anybody suggest how I debug this problem? Thanks

Updated: showing the generated data from PhysicsEditor

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you only probe for the first fixture. But complex bodies are made from several. The reason is that

- Box2d only allows 8 vertexes per fixture
- Box2d can only work with convex shapes

This is why complex shapes are decomposed into a list of polygons.

Iterate over the fixture list instead.

```
b2Fixture *f = body->GetFixtureList();
while(f)
{
    if(f -> TestPoint(v))
    {
        CCLog("You touched a body %d",sprite->getTag());
    }
    f = f->GetNext();            
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I think there is only one fixture for one body in my case, so I only get the first fixture. ( I actually did some tests like your suggestion. I'll do it again.)

"Box2d only allows 8 vertexes per fixture", does this mean I can at most add 8 vertexes for my sprite in PhysicsEditor?

Thanks

Comment: By the way, I added a screenshot for data generated by PhysicsEditor. It shows there is only one fixture for one sprite (for example, hotdog). But there are multiple arrays for polygons. There definitely more than 8 vertexes for a fixture.

Comment: I found PhysicsEditor automatically create more than one fixtures. But there are more than one polygons inside one fixtures. The total vertexes for these polygons will be more than 8. But it still work in your method. (I need to add a break after CCLog though. ) Anyway I'll test this in my real application which is cocos2d-x 2.0. I'll let you know the result. Thanks